# can controllers create arbitrary properties in the $rootScope in Angular

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

Is it legal for a controller to do something like this in Angular?

```
       $rootScope.someArbitaryObject = ["fee", "fie", "fo", "fum];
```

or

```
      $rootScope.foo = {name: "Jane Q. Public", favoriteColor: "green"}
```

Comment: ya it's legal, if you want it globally..

Comment: Is there a preferred way for controllers to share data?

Comment: yes, in services or using localstorage

Comment: yes there are multiple ways to do this.
1) Use events in angular $broadcast & $emit
http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/
2) Include $controller injecter on your controller injectors
angular.module("app.controllers",[]).controller('testCtrl',['$scope','$controller',function($scope,$controller){
 //controller scope you want to share in current scope.
     $controller('controllerName', { $scope: $scope });
}]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is legal but only if you want ALL controllers to have access to that model.

A better practice is to use services that you can then inject to one or more controllers:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('MyService', function () {
  return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.data = MyService;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.data = MyService;
});
```

Any change you make to MyService properties in one controller will affect all the other controllers that use MyService.

Comment: Do all controllers see the same instance of `MyService`, so that if FirstCtrl makes a change to `MyService.someProperty`, SecondCtrl sees the change?

Comment: You could probably guarantee that using .service rather than .factory

Comment: Yes, MyService is a singleton.

Comment: The helpful info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the question in your comments, a good way to share date is through localstorage (or sessionStorage). I wrote a storageService which allows you to save, load and delete.

```
angular.module(yourApplication).service('storageService', [
    function() {

        // implementation using localStorage. Future possibility to user $cookie service here, or sessionStorage, depends on what you want
        return {
            save: function(key, jsonData, expirationMin){ // default is 30 minute expiration
                if(!expirationMin)
                    expirationMin = 30;
                var expirationMS = expirationMin * 60 * 1000;
                var record = {
                    value: JSON.stringify(jsonData), 
                    timestamp: new Date().getTime() + expirationMS
                };
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(record));
                return jsonData;
            }, 
            load: function(key){
                var record = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                if (!record){ 
                    return false; 
                }
                return (new Date().getTime() < record.timestamp && JSON.parse(record.value));
            },
            remove: function(key){
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Another way using services (Modified Yoni's code a little):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('MyService', function () {
    var someData = 'test';
    return { 
        getData: function(){ return someData},
        setData: function(input){ someData = input;}
    };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.data = MyService.getData();
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.data = MyService.getData;
});
```

Comment: This will come in handy, EliteOctagon. Thanks for it. But at the moment I need to share dynamic, rapidly changing, rather than persisted data.